# How to make a smooth transition between drum patterns using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I am writing a music app which will let the user switch between different drum patterns "smoothly" by pressing desired buttons on screen. (By "smoothly" I mean the pattern will switch in the measure immediately following the time when the user presses a button).

My problem is that the time delay I am calculating for a delayed start of the next pattern is slightly larger than desired. I can fix by reducing the time delay by 0.1 sec, but this may not work if one uses a different tempo than the one I am currently using for testing.

The code which calculates the delay is:

```
func startClock() {
    let aSelector : Selector = "updateClock"
    clock = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
}

func stopClock() {
    clock.invalidate()
}

func updateClock() {
    currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime
    elapsedBeats = UInt(elapsedTime / audioMeterUpdateInterval)
    elapsedMeasures = UInt( Double(elapsedBeats) / Double(beatUnit[patternSelectIdx]) )

    requiredMeasures = elapsedMeasures + 1
    requiredBeats = requiredMeasures * UInt(beatUnit[patternSelectIdx])
    requiredTime = Double(requiredBeats) * audioMeterUpdateInterval

    delayTime = requiredTime - elapsedTime - 0.1 // 0.1 sec is chosen ad hoc

}
```

The code for one of the buttons for ending the drum patterns is:

```
@IBAction func endShort(sender: UIButton) {

    fileName = patternSelect + "End1"
    if startPlay == true {
        play(fileName, numberOfLoops: 0, delaySec: delayTime)
    } else {
        play(fileName, numberOfLoops: 0, delaySec: 0) 
    }
    playPauseButton.setImage(playImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    startPlay = false

}
```

Finally, the function `play` called by the above code is

```
func play(fileName: String, numberOfLoops: Int, delaySec: Double){

    if delaySec > 0 {
        let delayNSec = Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)*delaySec
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayNSec))

        self.ButtonAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = numberOfLoops
        self.ButtonAudioPlayer.volume = 1.0
        self.ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "wav")!)

        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.ButtonAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: self.ButtonAudioURL)
            self.ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
        })
    } else {
        ButtonAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = numberOfLoops
        ButtonAudioPlayer.volume = 1.0
        ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "wav")!)
        ButtonAudioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL)
        ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Is there an alternate approach to this? Also, can the 0.1 sec be a fixed delay related to the button animation time and hence always remain fixed and can be modified? Thanks!